# Macbook Pro USB Guitar Sound Issue

Tags: macbook-pro, usb

I bought a Neweer USB Guitar cable for my MacBook Pro 2015. When I connect it and try to use it it has a 1 second delay, and when I try to fix that with different options; i manage to fix the delay, but there is a scrambling sound that appears over time. This sound gradually increases in a matter of 10 seconds, and after that you can only hear this sound instead of the guitar. I tried everything, I don't know what to do.

Comment: This question may be closed due to the fact it's not about Apple hardware, and it's not clear what software you're using? You could try editing the question to explain _how_ you tried fixing it, otherwise we won't know if we're only suggesting the same things you've already tried. Also, have you tried getting help from Neweer or wherever you bought the cable from?

Answer (score 1):

You're never going to get zero latency. The amount of latency you do get will depend on buffer size, which should be settable in either the driver or your audio app's control panel. The smaller the buffer, the greater the processing power needed to achieve it, hence the breakup as you reduce it.

Investigate using any app that can use ASIO rather than the system drivers, & don't run any unnecessary apps at the same time.